# check if the mapped memory supports write combining

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I write a kernel driver which exposes to the user space my I/O device.
Using mmap the application gets virtual address to write into the device.
Since i want the application write uses a big PCIe transaction, the driver maps this memory to be write combining. 
According to the memory type (write-combining or non-cached) the application applies an optimal method to work with the device.

But, some architectures do not support write-combining or may support but just for part of the memory space. 
Hence, it is important that the kernel driver tell to application if it succeeded to map the memory to be write-combining or not.

I need a generic way to check in the kernel driver if the memory it mapped (or going to map) is write-combining or not. 
How can i do it?

here is part of my code:

vma->vm_page_prot = pgprot_writecombine(vma->vm_page_prot);
io_remap_pfn_range(vma, vma->vm_start, pfn, PAGE_SIZE, vma->vm_page_prot);

Answer (score 1):

First, you can find out if an architecture supports write-combining at compile time, with the macro `ARCH_HAS_IOREMAP_WC`. See, for instance, [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/asm-generic/iomap.h#L65).

At run-time, you can check the return values from [`ioremap_wc`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=ioremap_wc), or [`set_memory_wc`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/mm/pageattr.c#L1601) and friends for success or not.

Comment: but i try to map user-space to my device. hence i use mmap which handles the vm_area_struct and AFAIU ioremap_wc doesn't.

also, when ARCH_HAS_IOREMAP_WC is not defined,  does not necessarily mean that the arch does not support WC memory